# How to get logs for crashing graphics card

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, crash, gaming

I have PC with Windows 10 Home x64 and each time I try to play Subnautica Below Zero the game crashes after a minute. Other games play liquid. How can I figure out possible reasons on Windows or DX12? Is there anything similar to dmesg for Windows?

```
AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor 3.50 GHz
ATI Radeon HD 5850 1 GB
RAM 32 GB
```

[image]

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: SubnauticaZero.exe, Version: 2019.4.27.765, Zeitstempel: 0x6101cc48
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: d3d11.dll, Version: 10.0.19041.1202, Zeitstempel: 0x899ced78
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x000000000012c370
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x2654
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d8160aed000630
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Program Files\Subnautica Below Zero\SubnauticaZero.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
```

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for errors involving the game.

Comment: Look also in Reliability History for clues.  Control Panel, Security and maintenance, Maintenance, and click on reliability history.

Comment: Does your computer has a Driver Update App?  If so run that to update drivers to see if that helps the particular game.   Make sure you have a Windows 10 version of the game.

Comment: @John The only version for Windows is via Steam: https://store.steampowered.com/app/848450/Subnautica_Below_Zero/?utm_source=subnautica_com&utm_campaign=landing_page&utm_medium=web&utm_content=pc_button so it's for any Windows 7 or newer, Windows 10 recommended.

Comment: The problem is likely the 10 years old CPU: The minimum is Intel Core i3 / AMD Ryzen 3 2.6ghz+ (Intel Core i5 / AMD Ryzen 5 @ 3Ghz + recommended). The graphics albeit old as well still exceeds the minimum requirements - Intel HD 530 or better -, however way below the recommended Nvidia 1050 Ti / AMD Radeon 570. In conclusion, the overall system is far from ideal so problems ARE to be expected and it may not be possible to run, at all, again due to the ancient CPU.

Comment: made some effort with `SubnauticaZero.exe -force-opengl` (I don't have unity.exe on my computer) game seems to run now, will post it as answer after some hours successful gameplay

Comment: played for 1 hour now, looks stable. although I have solved my issue, question still applies. from file name d3d11.dll it looks like issue with DirectX11 to me (and Direct3D?) is there anything good like Event Viewer dxdiag or msinfo32 which can especially debug issues with DX or graphics card? are there any txt logfiles for this maybe? if someone can explain why/how `-force-opengl` solved the problem I will accept as answer too